# Extract marked strings from text file using Bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have files which are of the following style - these are parametrised configuration files; the values within the `#`characters are replaced with real values from a database depending on environment.

```
ABC=#PARAMETER_1#:#PARAMETER_2#
SOMETHING_ELSE=#PARAMETER_1#
SOMETHING_NEW=#PARAMETER_2##PARAMETER_3#
```

I would like to extract from these files the values between the hash/pound (`#`) characters, so that I can easily identify the parameters required. There is no standard column width or anything like that, the only standard being that anything between two `#` characters is replaced with a value from the database.

This is the ideal cleaned, deduped output:

```
PARAMETER_1
PARAMETER_2
PARAMETER_3
```

I have seen [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33697/finding-text-between-two-specific-characters-or-strings) question, but the crucial difference is that there can be any number of variables on a particular line in my situation.

I have tagged this question with Bash, but it doesn't have to be, it could be perl etc, it just needs to run from the command line in Unix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a first idea, `awk`:

```
awk -vRS='#[^#]+#' 'RT{gsub(/#/,"",RT);p[RT]=1}END{for(i in p)print i}' the_file
```

But this decision may depend on the other operations you have to perform.

---

**Explanations** as requested in comment.

```
awk -vRS='#[^#]+#' '   # use /#[^#]+#/ as record separator
RT {   # record terminator not empty?
  gsub(/#/,"",RT)    # remove the # parameter delimiter markup
  p[RT]=1   # store it as key in array p
}
END {   # end of input?
  for (i in p) print i   # loop through array p and print each key
}' the_file
```

The essential part is the use of `RT` (record terminator) built-in variable:

> ```
>    RT          The record terminator.  Gawk sets RT to the input text that
>                matched the character or regular expression specified by
>                RS.
> ```

Comment: That's amazing! Thanks - any links that explain how it works?

Comment: The only `awk` documentation I used to read is [The GNU Awk User's Guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html).

Comment: Just by the way, just `p[RT]` is quite enough to create the list of keys, ie, it doesn't require `=1`, as it never needs to access any values (it's actually faster, too) ... and also by the way, very nice +1.

Comment: @Peter.O, you are right. Assigning a value there was just by reflex.