# How can I pass output of one command as an argument to another

Tags: bash, pipe, git

A similar question has been asked, but since I am new to `Unix` the answer was not clear to me due to the context. What I want to do is to pass the output of one command as an argument to another. I am using git for source control and working on three different branches.

Whenever I need to commit I have to check my branch and then give the corresponding command as

```
git pull --rebase origin <branch-name>
```

I wanted to write an alias as `git-rebase` and what it would do is that first it will execute `git branch`.

The output of git branch look like this

```
experiment
*master
new feature
```

So if we have two branches in addition to the master branch then it will show all the branches and the current branch will be star marked. I want to extract the star marked line and then pass the output of this to the above command.

Also I would like to suppress the output of the command `git branch`. I am not doing this because I am too lazy to type the whole command, but because I would like to learn more about the power of unix bash. Hoping to learn something from it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to massage the `git branch` output into a useable format

```
$ git branch
  experiment
* master
  new feature

$ git branch | awk '/^\* / { print $2 }'
master
```

Now, you want to use that as an argument:

```
$ git pull --rebase origin $(git branch | awk '/^\* / { print $2 }')
```

(or you can use backticks as in psusi's answer).

This *should* be ok, the awk command should always match exactly one line, and I'm assuming you can't have spaces in branch names.  For anything much more complicated, I'd probably wrap it into a function (or a script) so you can do some sanity checking on the intermediate values.

Comment: I don't get it will the backticks solution work, because the output of git branch is not one branch name but as I pointed out all the branch names. And what does awk do?

Comment: @Sachin The awk code checks if a line begins with `* ` (`/^\* /` is a regexp match, the regexp is what's between the slashes); if it does, it prints the second word on the line (`$2`). So the output of `git branch | awk '/^\* / { print $2 }'` is just `master`.

Answer (score 4):

There is also the [`xargs`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs) command.

```
xargs - build and execute command lines from standard input
```

So the above answer from @Useless would translate to:

```
git branch | sed -ne 's/\*//p' | xargs git pull --rebase origin
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways.  The simplest is with backtick substitution:

```
git pull --rebase origin `git branch | sed -ne 's/\*//p'`
```

Comment: But as I said the command `git branch` gives us the names of all the branches and the current branch is star marked, so I need to extract that also?

Comment: Then you can use `sed` to extract just the line with the '*'.

Comment: @Sachin See [Extracting a regex matched with 'sed' without printing the surrounding characters](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31476/31479#31479) for common examples of sed usage.