# Only return the matched string in sed

Tags: sed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extracting a regex matched with 'sed' without printing the surrounding characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31476/extracting-a-regex-matched-with-sed-without-printing-the-surrounding-character)

How do I make this only print `test`:

```
echo "atestb" | sed -n 's/\(test\)/\1/p'
```

Comment: Must use `sed`? `grep`'s `-o` switch looks like a shorter and cleaner way: `echo "atestb" | grep -o 'test'`.

Comment: In case you are trying to output only the matching portion BETWEEN two known strings, try `echo "aSomethingYouWantb" | sed -En 's/a(.*)b/\1/p'`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You need to match the whole line:

```
echo "atestb" | sed -n 's/.*\(test\).*/\1/p'
```

or

```
echo "atestb" | sed 's/.*\(test\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: I had to add the `-r` or ` --regexp-extended` option otherwise I was getting `invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
` error.

Comment: @danielsokolowski: this example uses basic regular expressions (BRE) and thus capture groups are noted with escaped parentheses. If you add `-r` to the above you should get an error saying  "invalid reference". What version of sed are you using?

Comment: sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2 on cygwin

Comment: How does this answer the question of "only the string [that matched]". Matching the whole line was not in the question.

Comment: @jww: Did you test the answer? You need to match the whole line because it is a substitution command, i.e. you substitute the whole line with what was matched

Comment: I had to use `sed -rn 's/.*(MYPATTERN).*/\1/p'`

Comment: @Oliver: That is because of the `-r` which interprets the RE as an ERE. The default is to use BRE. [See this comparison for more detail](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-vs-ERE.html)

Comment: `echo "atetb" | sed 's/.*\(test\).*/\1/'` returns a non match, because it is substitution and not match

Comment: @kjeldflarup: it returns `test` as the OP requested