# extract fields from "tail -f" of a syslog stream

Tags: sed, awk, syslog, text

```
Example line from syslog file:
Aug  1 10:25:50 10.10.10.1 id=firewall sn=XXXX time="2012-08-01 14:35:18 UTC" fw=x.x.x.x pri=6 c=1024 m=537 msg="Connection Closed" f=11 n=195273698 src=x.x.x.x:60246:X3: dst=x.x.x.x:443:X6:host.domain.com proto=tcp/https sent=181793 rcvd=649678
```

I want to do a

```
$ tail -f /var/log/log.log | SOMETHING
```

That will return

```
"src=x.x.x.x dst=x.x.x.x"
```

In plainspeak I want to be able to extract specific fields from text. I do not want to select these fields based on a field number (position in the line) because the order of things can change slightly with the system generating this file, so it doesn't work.

Open to suggestions but would prefer it to be a one-liner.

Answer (score 4):

`tail -f log | perl -e 'while (<>) { print "src=$1 dst=$2\n" if $_ =~ /src=([^\s]+) dst=([^\s]+)/; }'`

Comment: I like it, and am intrigued by perl. Care to share a little bit of what's going on there? (trying to learn)

Comment: @LVLAaron, it try to match "src=XXX dst=YYY" on each line, where XXX and YYY are fields that contains no spaces or tabs, if got any match, it print matched part

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's/^.*\(src=[0-9.][0-9.]*\).*\(dst=[0-9.][0-9.]*\).*$/\1 \2/'
```

See [Extracting a regex matched with 'sed' without printing the surrounding characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31476/extracting-a-regex-matched-with-sed-without-printing-the-surrounding-character/31479#31479)

Answer (score 1):

grep has a `--line-buffered` option which allows you to follow `tail -f`

```
tail -f /var/log/messages | grep --line-buffered  'src=[0-9.]+\s+dst=[0-9.]+'
```

Comment: This returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

not quite as pretty but another solution implemented with awk:

```
tail -f /var/log/log.log | awk 'FS="src=" { print "src="$2 }' | awk 'FS=":" { print $1$4 }'`
```

**Update:** edited to be one line for `tail -f`

Comment: thank you @jw013. I didn't catch that. I revised it to a one liner.

Answer (score 0):

Or, improving a little on warlOck's:

`tail -f log | perl -n -e 'print "$1 $2\n" if /(src=[^\s]+) (dst=[^\s]+)/;'`

(I haven't figured out how to comment on an answer yet...)