# How to search many files with regular expression and output matches to lines in a new file?

Tags: bash, regular-expression, search

I have 1000's of source files and I would like to find all text that matches a regular expression and then output each match on its own line in a resulting text file.

For instance;

```
// a.cs
string test = _.Text("Hello World!") + _.Text("Foo");
// b.cs
Debug.Log(_.ActionText("Bar"));

// results.txt
_.Text("Hello World")
_.Text("Foo")
_.ActionText("Bar")
```

Which command would is capable of achieving this? could you please show an example?

Comment: If your `grep` supports `-o`, that would be the best candidate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed '/\n/P;//!s/_\.[^ ("]*Text([^)]*)/\n&\n/;D' files... >results.txt
```

...would probably work. Run on your example data it prints:

```
_.Text("Hello World!")
_.Text("Foo")
_.ActionText("Bar")
```

All it does is attempt to enclose the first match on a line in `\n`ewlines. Whether or not it succeeds it `D`eletes up to the first `\n`ewline in pattern space - which for a non-matching line completely removes it from output, but for a match deletes only up to the head of your pattern and the script starts again from the top. If a `\n`ewline is matched in pattern space - which can only happen if a match was just found and then `D`eleted - then `sed` prints only up to the first occurring `\n`ewline in pattern space - which is at the tail of your matched string. The `s///`ubstitution is `!`not attempted when there is a `\n`ewline already in pattern space, so the `D`elete command clears the already printed match and the cycle starts again from the tail of the last match on.

Depending on your `sed` you may need to use a literal `\n`ewline in place of the `n` in the right-hand substitution field, though. But you should be able to do all of the file arguments at once - or, at least, very many at a time *(depending on your ARGMAX limits)*. You can just shell glob for those, or maybe do...

```
find /path -name pattern -exec sed script_above {} + >>results.txt
```

...because `sed` will treat all input files as a single stream.

Comment: I went with the `find` approach and it worked perfectly; thanks!

Comment: @LeaHayes - I'm very pleased to know it - and thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep.

```
grep -Eo '_\.\w+\("[^"]+"\)'
```